# Excel set a hyperlink column to another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink, excel-2010

I have an Excel file with two columns, the first column is normal text, and another column is a hyperlink, I hope to generate a 3rd column, which shows the text in the 1st column but when click it, it will directly go to the link from the 2nd column. Any help please?

e.g.

```
Item   Link         Combine
abc   www.aqwe.com  abc(click this cell go to the link)
xva   www.blah.com  xva(click this cell go to the link)
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HYPERLINK()` function.

```
=HYPERLINK(B2,A2)
```

[image]